# "There are multiple root elements" error when previewing Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, xmlparsing

We have an Order Confirmation email that is currently working, but requires some updates to the creative.

After making the edits we get an error when trying to preview the email.

The preview error also exists when viewing the unedited and working Triggered Email too.

Here is the error from SFMC; admittedly, I'm not an XML expert

```
Invalid xml found in xml parameter. Function: BuildRowSetFromXML(@shipXML, "/shipmentItem/shipping-method", 0). 
See inner exception for details 

An exception occurred while retrieving the XML document for string 
    [<status>
      <shipping-status>NOT_SHIPPED</shipping-status>
     </status>
       <shipping-method>001</shipping-method>
         <shipping-address>
           <first-name>Redacted</first-name>
           <last-name>Redacted</last-name>
           <address1>Redacted</address1>
           <address2>Redacted</address2>
           <city>Toronto</city>
           <postal-code>Redacted</postal-code>
           <state-code>ON</state-code>
           <country-code>CA</country-code>


            <phone>Redacted</phone>
             </shipping-address>

           <gift>false</gift>

          <totals>
            <merchandize-total>
               <net-price>59.99</net-price>
               <tax>7.80</tax>
               <gross-price>67.79</gross-price>
             </merchandize-total>
               <adjusted-merchandize-total>
               <net-price>59.99</net-price>
               <tax>7.80</tax>
               <gross-price>67.79</gross-price>
             </adjusted-merchandize-total>

          <shipping-total>
               <net-price>6.62</net-price>
               <tax>0.00</tax>
               <gross-price>6.62</gross-price>
          </shipping-total>

        <adjusted-shipping-total>
           <net-price>0.00</net-price>
           <tax>0.00</tax>
           <gross-price>0.00</gross-price>
        </adjusted-shipping-total>

        <shipment-total>
            <net-price>59.99</net-price>
            <tax>7.80</tax>
            <gross-price>67.79</gross-price>
            </shipment-total></totals>].  

There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 65.
```

Question:  How does this email work today if we can't preview it using the same data?
Question:  What can we do to resolve the XML issue?  Is it actually an issue?

Thank you!

Comment: You're problem's as per the error. There are multiple root elements (status, shipping-method, shipping-address...) in your XML that you're trying to parse into a rowset. XML requires a single root element within which these elements are nested. You'll need to fix hour XML to get BuildRowSetFromXML() to successfully parse its content.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to correct it... for some reason the emails deploy via API but when I preview using the Triggered DE, I get the error above.  Can't say I know why, nor can I figure out how to fix it.

I tried using `Replace()` but that simply moved the error to a different position

Comment: If you were adding a single root, like <order> around the existing xml, you would have something valid there I guess. But that doesnt explain your first question.
In regards to your first question: Could it be that the code was altered after the triggered send was activated? The email in the triggered send is only updated if you republish the triggered send.

Comment: SUPER STRANGE!!!

I just copy/pasted the HTML into a new message and it rendered... not perfectly, but it did.  When I tried to preview the original, it failed again.  In addition, after doing many back-and-forth Send Previews, the error popped up again!